# Can I attack a Bulette when it's underground?

Tags: dnd-4e, monsters

Do other characters know where the bulette is if it doesn't attack? If they can attack it, how do I handle it? Do I give it total cover? Can they even attack it when it is underground?

If they don't know where it is and they want to guess, how do I randomize that? Or should I just take the creature off of the board when it is underground and try to remember where it is?

Comment: I hate those things!

Comment: very closely related - http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6810/where-are-the-dnd-4e-rules-for-perceiving-burrowed-creatures

Comment: Also, don't forget the rules of "hidden club." Just because a monster has total concealment doesn't mean that it's hidden unless it's succeeded on a stealth roll.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, [burrowing](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=345) creatures are free from attack because there will be no [line of effect](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=543) from an attacker above ground.  If the creature has [tunneling](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=422), then it will leave passages behind which may grant line of effect to some attackers.

The Bulette's current position and movements should be known to all unless it is [hidden](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4828/when-a-creature-is-invisible-but-not-hidden-do-the-enemies-know-the-location-o).